# Restkit via cocoapods fails to build on new project, RKLog not found

Tags: ios, ios6, restkit, cocoapods

I'm trying to use Restkit via CocoaPods for my first time, on a brand new project, but I encounter some issues building the project once Restkit is introduced:

[image]

I have followed these exact steps:

1. Created a brand new Xcode project, default options.
2. Created a podfile with the following contents :

   platform :ios, '6.1' 
   pod 'RestKit/Testing', '~> 0.20.0pre'
   pod 'RestKit/Search',  '~> 0.20.0pre'
3. Run `pod install` then opened the workspace
4. Updated the prefix file as instructed [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods).

I'm running these versions, all valid according to the Restkit documentation:

- Git git version 1.8.1.2
- CocoaPods 0.16.2
- Xcode 4.6

Can anyone suggest what I may have done wrong, or what I can do to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the base of Restkit as well. Add

```
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0pre'
```

To your Podfile.

Answer (score 1):

[Found a solution described here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/832).

It involves searching the project for #import  and replacing it with #import . The project compiles!

```
//#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/CoreData.h>
```

In this case the offending file was `RKOperationStateMachine`